# Can you Integrate a Cookiecutter template with the Github Template repository feature?

Tags: templates, github, cookiecutter

At the moment I'm planning to write a python template for my company in order to have a consistent structure through all the different projects and channel some best practices.

To do so it seems a good idea to use the [Cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) method of generating templates on the one hand and the [GitHub Template repository feature](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template) on the other hand. Now I'm curious if one can combine both methods, I have something like this in my mind:

- The user creates a new GitHub repo within the website by using the GitHub Template repository feature
- Then he clones it on his local machine
- Then he can run Cookiecutter locally and populate the project with his details
- Finally he just needs to push the nicely initialized template back to GitHub and overwrite the old defaults

Is it possible to use such a workflow?
How would I do it?

Of course it would be even cooler if GitHub could integrate Cookiecutter in its GitHub Template repository feature; like asking you all the question within the website.

Comment: I would use the github feature within cookiecutter then run a git init. I'm not sure how the github template repo would add value to the project
https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/usage.html#works-directly-with-git-and-hg-mercurial-repos-too

PS I agree that it would be cool if cookiecutter included a git init feature that automatically generated a repo as part of the directory creation process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same task. Following this [post](https://adriaanrol.com/posts/setting_up_a_python_project/) (that is for gitlab, for github is a bit different), this workflow worked for me:

1. Create a **completely empty** repository in github. Write down the repository name (e.g. `cookiecutter-test`) and the repository link (e.g. https://github.com/nepentabits/cookiecutter-test.git)
2. In your local machine, create the cookie project, with a slug name (the top directory of the project that you will populate) with the same name as the repo, for example (the template will be yours, and in my case the repo is `cookiecutter-test`)

```
$ cookiecutter https://xx@dev.azure.com/xx/ama-template-data-science
$ ...
$ ls
$ cookiecutter-test
```

3. Go inside the local package (in my case `cookiecutter-test`) and perform the `git` commands *exactly in the same order*. This is due to the fact that in most git local installations the branch is called `master` while in github they call it `main`, and for changing branch names in local, you have to have a commit first. Also, this works if the github repo is completely empty. Substitute

```
$ git init 
$ git add . 
$ git commit -m "First commit with cookiecutter scaffold" 
$ git branch -M main
$ # the repo link should yours one
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/nepentabits/cookiecutter-test.git
$ git push -u origin main
```

In the last step will ask you for your github name and https token.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub Template feature is nice because (a) it shows up in the "create repo" menu and (b) the new repo retains an understanding of where it came from in GitHub, which is useful metadata.

That said, the feature seems pretty limited, otherwise. You can integrate a cookiecutter workflow into that, and we have looked into it, but I'm not sure the two small value-adds above are worth the hassle of trying to mix the two approaches.

If you do decide to go down that route, probably the best you can do is just have a really good README.md in the template that tells you what to do (i.e., run cookiecutter as soon as you've cloned the repo, check in the changes, push them back). You could also have the new repo include a GitHub action that runs cookiecutter itself, and checks in the changes, but at this point you are building a bit of a Rube Goldberg machine around three tools (GitHub Templates, GitHub Actions, and Cookiecutter) that are not really designed to be used this way.

One downside to using cookiecutter inside an existing repo is that it will create a new folder *inside* your repo rather than replace the whole repo, and I don't think there are any easy ways around that. For your usecases, that might be fine? or even desirable? (e.g., a mono repo containing microservices).

Side note: if you just have a couple of templates, GitHub Templates will work fine, but there's no metadata around the templates, so someone using them has to figure out for themselves which templates are up-to-date, supported, etc., so it doesn't currently scale terribly well to a large organisation.

I think you're better off using either/or.

Comment: That is what I did in the end. I only use cookiecutter at the moment and that is good enough for me at the moment.